# How can I open a program on second monitor using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, multiple-monitors

I am going to run a script in cmd on a multi-monitor (multi-screen) computer with two monitors. In this script, I will call and run another program. One of these monitors is located in another room. (Let us call it monitor number 0). These two screens are in extended mode. Extending monitors means that your computer interprets the monitors that you are extending as separate devices. You can see different things on each monitor, and your desktop background is displayed on each monitor.

The problem is that this program will show on the monitor number 0 (which I cannot see the results). In fact, I want to see the output on my own screen.

So, the question is that why everything shows on monitor number 0 and how I can tell to powershell/cmd to show the result on monitor number 1.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can find your answer [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start-winpc/opening-programs-on-second-monitor-not-main/ebc1d56d-8b75-47d4-91b8-64ea71cc206a).

Comment: Thanks man for your answer. I already saw this web page. The problem is that I cannot see the first monitor in the separated room.
I need a PowerShell command like this:  

>powershell notepad++.exe --monitor=1